# Ambiguous Method call in Java with Generic VarArgs

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions

I'm getting a compile error `The method getRecommendedIds(String, Object&Comparable<?>&Serializable[]) is ambiguous for the type MyService` when trying to call an overloaded method that uses generics and varargs.

The service:

```
public interface MyService {
    public <K> List<K> getRecommendedIds(String datasource, K... ids);
    public <K> List<K> getRecommendedIds(String datasource, int limit, K... ids);
}
```

The call:

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void testGetWithLimitThrowsNpeForNullDatasource() {
    service.getRecommendedIds(null, 3, UUID.randomUUID());
}
```

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the K variable is not bounded the call is indeed ambiguous - it could be a call to the three-argument version, or it could be a call to the `(String, K...)` version with the 3 autoboxed as an `Integer` and `K` bound to `Object`.  If you call it as

```
service.<UUID>getRecommendedIds(null, 3, UUID.randomUUID());
```

with an explicit binding for K it will work because neither `int` nor `Integer` is assignable to the `UUID` type, so the call must be to the three arg version.  You could also get away without the explicit bound if you assigned the return value of the call to a variable that restricts the type, i.e.

```
List<UUID> ids = service.getRecommendedIds(null, 3, UUID.randomUUID());
```

Here the compiler must bind `K` to `UUID` to make the return types match.

Comment: Thanks! I tried switching the int and String parameters around, and that works, but I really don't understand why! Any ideas?

Comment: Because then it's no longer ambiguous - the two methods are distinguished by their first parameter which is not a type variable (it's either `int` or `String`).

Comment: Ah yes, thinking it through that makes quite obvious sense :)